# Append Map(key, Set[value]) in a Map to existing Key in Scala 2.11

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm trying to append a new value to the Set(Values) for an existing key, but it is replacing the existing value.

This is my input

```
val roads = Array(Array(0,1),Array(0,2),Array(1,2))
```

Expected output:

```
Map(0 -> Set(1,2),1 -> Set(2))
```

My Code:

```
  val roads = Array(Array(0,1),Array(0,2),Array(1,2))
  var adjMatrix:Map[Int,Set[Int]] = Map()

  for(i <- 0 until roads.size; j <- 1 until roads(i).size){
    adjMatrix += (roads(i)(0) -> Set(roads(i)(j)))
  }
```

and when I do

```
  adjMatrix.foreach(println)
```

I get below result, as there are two keys with 0 name, it replaces the (0,1) element at the 0th index

```
(1,Set(2))
(0,Set(2))
```

Comment: It can have more than two elements, but the first element would always be the key and rest of the elements are values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
roads
  .groupBy(a => a(0))
  .map { case (key, value) => key -> (value.flatten.toSet - key) }
```

which outputs

```
Map(1 -> Set(2), 0 -> Set(1, 2))
```

Comment: I modified your solution a bit :
roads.groupBy(a => a(0)).map(a => Map(a._1 -> (a._2.flatten.toSet - a._1)))

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is to first extract the key of each group.
Then, [`groupBy`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.11/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@groupBy[K](f:A=%3EK):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,Repr]) that key.
And finally, join all values and turn them into a final **Set**.

*(Note: I changed **Array** with **List** as extracting the `tail` of an array is a very costly operation.)*

```
val roads = List(List(0,1),List(0,2),List(1,2))

val adjMatrix =
  roads.map {
    case x :: xs => x -> xs // This may fail if the list is empty!
  } groupBy {
    case (key, _) => key
  } map {
    case (key, values) => key -> values.flatMap(_._2).toSet // _._2 === case (_, values) => values.
  }

// adjMatrix: Map[Int, Set[Int]] = Map(1 -> Set(2), 0 -> Set(1, 2))
```

**PS:** I would recommend you to upgrade to at least Scala `2.12`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Apache Spark version in our project is not compatible with 2.12, so it's not feasible to upgrade to 2.12 right now.